# Rbind some files with same names in different folders in R

Tags: r

I have some folder I have a txt file named `PredictedRecognitionPotentials`

I want to rbind these files from different folders into one unfied txt files

How I can do that in R because I don't have access to shell?

```
> file <- "PredictedRecognitionPotentials.txt"

> mydirs <- c("/Users/Angel/Desktop/r/LP6005334","/Users/Angel/Desktop/r/LP6005500","/Users/Angel/Desktop/r/LP6007600","/Users/Angel/Desktop/r/LP6008202",
+   "/Users/Angel/Desktop/r/LP6008334-DNA_A03","/Users/Angel/Desktop/r/LP6008334-DNA_A04","/Users/Angel/Desktop/r/LP6008334-DNA_B02","/Users/Angel/Desktop/r/LP6008334-DNA_C02",
+   "/Users/Angel/Desktop/r/LP6008334-DNA_D02","/Users/Angel/Desktop/r/LP6008336-DNA_F02","/Users/Angel/Desktop/r/LP6008336-DNA_G01","/Users/Angel/Desktop/r/LP6008336-DNA_H01",
+   "/Users/Angel/Desktop/r/LP6008337-DNA_A07","/Users/Angel/Desktop/r/LP6008337-DNA_H06","/Users/Angel/Desktop/r/LP6008460-DNA_A04","/Users/Angel/Desktop/r/LP6008460-DNA_D01",
+   "/Users/Angel/Desktop/r/LP6008460-DNA_F02","/Users/Angel/Desktop/r/LP6008460-DNA_G03","/Users/Angel/Desktop/r/SLX-18929_UDP0015","/Users/Angel/Desktop/r/SLX-18929_UDP0018",
+   "/Users/Angel/Desktop/r/SLX-18929_UDP0024","/Users/Angel/Desktop/r/SLX-18929_UDP0030","/Users/Angel/Desktop/r/SLX-18929_UDP0059","/Users/Angel/Desktop/r/SLX-18929_UDP0067",
+   "/Users/Angel/Desktop/r/SLX-18929_UDP0080","/Users/Angel/Desktop/r/SLX-18929_UDP0086","/Users/Angel/Desktop/r/SLX-18929_UDP0094")
> res <- do.call(rbind, lapply(paste0(mydirs, file), read.table))
Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(file, "rt") :
  cannot open file '/Users/Angel/Desktop/r/LP6005334PredictedRecognitionPotentials.txt': No such file or directory


> res <- do.call(rbind, lapply(paste0(mydirs, "/"), read.table))
Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(file, "rt") :
  cannot open file '/Users/Angel/Desktop/r/LP6005334//': Permission denied

> res <- rbindlist(lapply(files, fread), fill = TRUE)
Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : 
  File '/Users/Angel/Desktop/r/SLX-18929_UDP0067//PredictedRecognitionPotentials.txt' does not exist or is non-readable. getwd()=='C:/Users/Angel/Desktop/r'
> 

> res <- map_dfr(files, read_table)

-- Column specification --------------------------------------------------------------
cols(
  `NeoantigenID Mutation    Sample  MutatedPeptide  ResidueChangeClass  MutantPeptide   WildtypePeptide HLA Expression  A   R   Excluded    NeoantigenRecognitionPotential` = col_character()
)


-- Column specification --------------------------------------------------------------
cols(
  `NeoantigenID Mutation    Sample  MutatedPeptide  ResidueChangeClass  MutantPeptide   WildtypePeptide HLA A   R   Excluded    NeoantigenRecognitionPotential` = col_character()
)


Error: '/Users/Angel/Desktop/r/SLX-18929_UDP0067//PredictedRecognitionPotentials.txt' does not exist.







> mydirs
 [1] "/Users/Angel/Desktop/r/LP6005334/PredictedRecognitionPotentials"        
 [2] "/Users/Angel/Desktop/r/LP6005500/PredictedRecognitionPotentials"        
 [3] "/Users/Angel/Desktop/r/LP6007600/PredictedRecognitionPotentials"        
 [4] "/Users/Angel/Desktop/r/LP6008202/PredictedRecognitionPotentials"        
 [5] "/Users/Angel/Desktop/r/LP6008334-DNA_A03/PredictedRecognitionPotentials"
 [6] "/Users/Angel/Desktop/r/LP6008334-DNA_A04/PredictedRecognitionPotentials"
 [7] "/Users/Angel/Desktop/r/LP6008334-DNA_B02/PredictedRecognitionPotentials"
 [8] "/Users/Angel/Desktop/r/LP6008334-DNA_C02/PredictedRecognitionPotentials"
 [9] "/Users/Angel/Desktop/r/LP6008334-DNA_D02/PredictedRecognitionPotentials"
[10] "/Users/Angel/Desktop/r/LP6008336-DNA_F02/PredictedRecognitionPotentials"
[11] "/Users/Angel/Desktop/r/LP6008336-DNA_G01/PredictedRecognitionPotentials"
[12] "/Users/Angel/Desktop/r/LP6008336-DNA_H01/PredictedRecognitionPotentials"
[13] "/Users/Angel/Desktop/r/LP6008337-DNA_A07/PredictedRecognitionPotentials"
[14] "/Users/Angel/Desktop/r/LP6008337-DNA_H06/PredictedRecognitionPotentials"
[15] "/Users/Angel/Desktop/r/LP6008460-DNA_A04/PredictedRecognitionPotentials"
[16] "/Users/Angel/Desktop/r/LP6008460-DNA_D01/PredictedRecognitionPotentials"
[17] "/Users/Angel/Desktop/r/LP6008460-DNA_F02/PredictedRecognitionPotentials"
[18] "/Users/Angel/Desktop/r/LP6008460-DNA_G03/PredictedRecognitionPotentials"
[19] "/Users/Angel/Desktop/r/SLX-18929_UDP0015/PredictedRecognitionPotentials"
[20] "/Users/Angel/Desktop/r/SLX-18929_UDP0018/PredictedRecognitionPotentials"
[21] "/Users/Angel/Desktop/r/SLX-18929_UDP0024/PredictedRecognitionPotentials"
[22] "/Users/Angel/Desktop/r/SLX-18929_UDP0030/PredictedRecognitionPotentials"
[23] "/Users/Angel/Desktop/r/SLX-18929_UDP0059/PredictedRecognitionPotentials"
[24] "/Users/Angel/Desktop/r/SLX-18929_UDP0067/PredictedRecognitionPotentials"
[25] "/Users/Angel/Desktop/r/SLX-18929_UDP0080/PredictedRecognitionPotentials"
[26] "/Users/Angel/Desktop/r/SLX-18929_UDP0086/PredictedRecognitionPotentials"
[27] "/Users/Angel/Desktop/r/SLX-18929_UDP0094/PredictedRecognitionPotentials"
> res <- do.call(rbind, lapply(paste0(mydirs, file), read.table))
Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(file, "rt") :
  cannot open file '/Users/Angel/Desktop/r/LP6005334/PredictedRecognitionPotentialsPredictedRecognitionPotentials.txt': No such file or directory
> res <- do.call(rbind, lapply(paste0(mydirs, "/"), read.table))
Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(file, "rt") :
  cannot open file '/Users/Angel/Desktop/r/LP6005334/PredictedRecognitionPotentials/': No such file or directory
> 
>
```

Comment: The error shows `//` slash between the file and the last subfolder.  It should be `/`

Comment: If I do `mydirs <-  c("/Users/Angel/Desktop/r/LP6005334","/Users/Angel/Desktop/r/LP6005500","/Users/Angel/Desktop/r/LP6007600","/Users/Angel/Desktop/r/LP6008202"); file <- "PredictedRecognitionPotentials.txt"; file.path(mydirs, file)
[1] "/Users/Angel/Desktop/r/LP6005334/PredictedRecognitionPotentials.txt" "/Users/Angel/Desktop/r/LP6005500/PredictedRecognitionPotentials.txt"
[3] "/Users/Angel/Desktop/r/LP6007600/PredictedRecognitionPotentials.txt" "/Users/Angel/Desktop/r/LP6008202/PredictedRecognitionPotentials`

Comment: I tested both on Mac and Windows and it is working on both

Comment: The issue as showed in the last update is `"/Users/Angel/Desktop/r/LP6005334/PredictedRecognitionPotentials"` you don't have `.csv` at the end.  I was using the `mydirs` from your initial post `mydirs <- c("/Users/Angel/Desktop/r/LP6005334", ..`

Comment: It would be helpful if you could remove those additional `>` and `+` from the code so that it is easier for us to copy your code directly into R. Now we need to manually remove them from each line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `list.files` with  the `path` on the parent directory path, then specify `recursive = TRUE` to check all the subdirectories for the file mentioned in the `pattern`

```
files <- list.files(path = "/Users/Angel/Desktop/r/",
  pattern = "PredictedRecognitionPotentials\\.txt$" 
                 recursive = TRUE, full.names = TRUE)
```

---

Or make use of `file.path` to construct the file path from the already created folder vector and the file

```
files <- file.path(mydirs, file)
```

Then, we can either use `tidyverse` or `base R` in reading the data

```
library(purrr)
library(readr)
res <- map_dfr(files, read_table)
```

---

Or we can use `fread` from `data.table` for faster read

```
library(data.table)
res <- rbindlist(lapply(files, fread), fill = TRUE)
```

Comment: Sorry I added my new errors to my main files

Comment: @Mussa I think you overwrote the `mydirs` with some pasted values.  If you use the first version of `mydirs` with the `file`, it would work

Answer (score 1):

Using `read.table`, then `rbind`. Something like

```
file <- "file_xy.txt"
mydirs <- c("X:/dir1/", "X:/dir2/")
res <- do.call(rbind, lapply(paste0(mydirs, file), read.table))
outdir <- "X:/outdir/"
write.table(res, file=paste0(outdir, "all.txt"))
```

Comment: I have added your kindly answer in the main post which I got error

Comment: @Mussa I believe there's just a slash missing at the end of the dirs, so the strings get pasted without a slash in between. Try again with `mydirs <- paste0(mydirs , "/")`.